# What are the best deployment Tools & Best Practices for Drupal Sites Databases

Tags: drupal, deployment, capistrano, drush, webistrano

I've been asked to help the Developpement Team of an information/news centric website based on drupal 7 with the goal of automating the deployment from staging to production, Currently everything is done manually and lots of mistakes are made, thus delaying the official launch of the website. I'm well aquainted with Tools like phing to deploy PHP applications developed with zend framework or symfony and i have small knowledge about Capistrano.

After some research here and there, i have stumbled upon certains tools whose combination could be a good formula for automated deployment:

- Drush + Capistrano
- Migraine

I'm looking for best practices first as their launch date is very close and Tools for later implementation as i presume it will take times before they truly master something capistrano/drush to automate deployment of both files and settings stored in drupal's DB.

Comment: What route did you end up taking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One current trend in Drupal development is to move site configuration out of the database and into code using the [features module](http://drupal.org/project/features).  Nuvole made an [excellent presentation](http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/zero-distribution-using-features-profiler-and-drush-make) on this (although it regards making Drupal distributions, the concerns for large-scale sites are similar.  By moving site configuration to code, many errors can be eliminated as you can just use your existing version control system to manage deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best practices of Drupal project deployment is using Features module and Drush. Using these tools will be discussed at [this webinar](http://www.qarea.com/webinars/drupal-deployment-features-module-drush), if you're interested.